# what is the purpose of binding and unbinding the same javascript function?

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I know what jquery bind() and unbind() does. But What is the purpose of binding and unbinding the same function using jquery function. In a large code base, I saw binding and binding a function in places. for ex.

```
$('#someButtonID').unbind('click',functionName)
                  .bind('click',functionName);
```

What is the need of doing it?

Comment: how about preventing to bind it twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single event it is possible to bind many functions. 
So this code:

```
$('#someButtonID').unbind('click',funtionName).bind('click',functionName);
```

makes sure that the function with name `functionName` is bound to the element only once (execute only once per click of the element), other wise you wont know how many times the function wil be called.